# Can OS X applications linked against JavaVM Framework run with Oracle's JRE 1.7?

Tags: java, macos

I'm trying to figure out how all the different JDKs/JREs available on Mac interact. I have created a dummy Cocoa Application project in XCode 4.6 on Lion, and added the JavaVM.framework. I also added a #include  just to make sure it's in the search path, and built the app.
When I try to run the app on a Mountain Lion machine, with no Java installed, OS X prompts to install Java for OS X 2013-002, and runs the application if it's installed. 
To my surprise, OS X will still try to install this, even if Oracle's JRE or JDK (1.7) is already installed on the machine.

Is there a way to leave the choice to the user as to which JRE he wants to install, without loosing the fallback prompt Apple provides to let users install a JRE if they need that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to leave the choice to the user as to which JRE he wants to install, without loosing the fallback prompt Apple provides to let users install a JRE if they need that?

No.

`JavaVM.framework` is only for Apple Javas, and as you have discovered it will ignore any Oracle Java 7 JREs or JDKs that happen to be installed on the machine.  Likewise, if you use Oracle's `<appbundler>` task to build a `.app` that works with Oracle Java 7 it will not use Apple Java 6.  I believe the recommended approach these days is to bundle an Oracle JRE inside your `.app` (something `<appbundler>` can do for you) and use that one rather than relying on a system-wide Java installation.